# Is there a free Mac OS X MS Exchange e-mail notifier?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, email, notifications, exchange-2010

I have searched high and low for a simple menubar / background notifier for an MS Exchange account, preferably something that could connect to Growl, but no luck. If you know of such a thing, I would be very grateful! OS X 10.6.7. (PS: I know I can make Outlook '11 growl its new messages, but I want a lightweight background type app so I can leave Outlook closed except when necessary.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. (No no no no no 30 chars.)

Answer (score 1):

What about using Mac OS X Mail.app for getting at the Mails? That should be more light-weight than Outlook. As for Growl, there is a [GrowlMail](http://growl.info/growlmail/) thingy...

Comment: A good thought, but Mail is heavier than what I'm looking for in just a notifier, but does not support mailing lists independent of the Apple contacts list which, along with a couple of other minor reasons, forces me to use Outlook for my actual mail handling. Thanks though!